# CORS Headers missing from basic API response apnetnet core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I have just created a default dotnet core 3.0 API project with the basic weather forecast API. I wanted to get CORS working before I did anything else with the project.

In startup i have the following code....

```
private readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I am not doing anything special or seemingly incorrect. This is directly from the MSDN documentation....
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0

The problem is that when sending requests through both the browser and postman, There are none of the expected headers in the given responses.

I have googled the crap out of this and have not got anywhere. Am i missing something? could it be environmental? has it changed from a previous version of core?

Comment: Can you show the CURL version of the request that you are sending

Comment: @Roooss
Did you solve the problem? scratching head with the same problem CORS not working .Net Core 3.0

Comment: IT did turn out to be ordering IIRC